# Filing labels with color

Tags: java, label

I have Grid of labels (size n*n) and I want to fill with color its irregular part. I wrote a method

```
private void fill(int j){

    while(board[j].getName().equals("s")){
       board[j].setBackground(Color.yellow);

       try{
            fill(j-1);   
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}

       try{
            fill(j+1);     
       } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}

       try{
            fill(j+n);  
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}

       try{
            fill(j-n);   
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){}

    }
}
```

and I'm still getting StackOverflowError. I'm not using big parts (my n is max 20), I've tried to replace while with if, but didn't work too. Is it too big for a stack or might be there infinite loop? How I can fix that?

Comment: What is termination condition for your recursive call?  what min and max value you expect **j** to hold

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say that for some reason for

- `j` and `j-1` condition in `while` will are satisfied,
- for rest values like `j-2` not

So if you invoke `fill(j)` program will

1. test `while` condition for `j` (pass)
2. enter `while` loop
3. `setBackground` for `j`
4. invoke `fill(j-1);`.

   Now before program will invoke `fill(j+1)`, program will have to finish `fill(j-1)` so flow of control will be moved to `fill(j-1)` level and program  will

   1. test `while` condition for `j-1` (pass)
   2. you enter `while` loop
   3. `setBackground` for `j-1`
   4. invoke `fill((j-1)-1);` in other words `fill(j-2)`.

      And again before `fill((j-1)+1)` flow of control will be moved to `fill(j-2)` so program will

      1. test `while` condition for `j-2` (fail)
      2. program cant enter loop so will return return from fill(j-2)
   5. invoke `fill((j-1)+1)` which is the same as `fill(j)`

So your application will try to repeat the same scenario, but this time on different stack level which will lead to StackOverwlow.

---

To prevent this situation maybe change condition to also test if you already been at this position, like

```
while(board[j].getName().equals("s") && board[j].getBackground() != Color.yellow)
```

You can/should also change `while` to `if`.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But do you know how can I cut it to borders? Where have I to break/return to avoid coloring labels in next line when labels in previous lines are colored?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. You should probably create another question and describe your situation showing that you have and what you want to have.

Comment: I have square n x n. In some cases label j+1 could be the first in next line of labels and it would be colored but I don't want it

Comment: @user2420287 If you numbered your labels from `0` to `n*n-1` then I suspect that first labels in each row will have index that `index % n == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

`board[j].setName("bgSet")`

after

`board[j].setBackground(Color.yellow)`

this might solve the problem, otherwise your while is always true.